# Random number with VBA

Tags: vba, random

I am trying to create random numbers in within normal distribution given random probabilities in a range. My code is the following:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(RandomNumbers + 1, 1)) = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd)
```

Where `RandomNumbers` is just a value in another cell. The problem is that if `RandomNumbers` is equal to, lets say, 10 then `VBA` fills the same random number in all 10 cells. How do I make every number different in every cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a loop:

```
Dim cell as Range
For Each cell In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(RandomNumbers + 1, 1))
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd)
Next
```